# When there are multiple "spawn" statements in the expect script, only the last spawn statement is executed fully

Tags: linux, bash, expect, spawn

From expect script, I am calling two other shell scripts. But only the second shell script seems to get executed properly. Because the output statements of the first shell script is not seen in the screen.
This is my expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /bin/bash test1.sh
spawn /bin/bash test2.sh
interact
```

Why is this happening? And what is the fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wait for the first *spawn*ed process to finish:

```
spawn /bin/bash test1.sh
expect eof

spawn /bin/bash test2.sh
interact
```